# Azure B2C and ADFS

Tags: adfs, azure-ad-b2c

I understand that the use of Azure B2C and ADFS together is not supported.

What are my options if I need both Facebook/Google for customers and ADFS for partners?

I know creating my own STS using IdentityServer, and fedearating to Azure B2C or ADFS would be an option, but then again - building my own STS is what I hope to avoid.

Regards
Larsi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

B2C can federate with ADFS. Follow [B2C MSDN Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-adfs2016-idp) to federate.

**OLD ANSWER**

B2C at the moment does not allow federation to other STS.

Also it only supports OpenID Connect which is only available on ADFS 4.0 - Server 2016.

You can get this working by using IdentityServer as a bridge. Hook ADFS up via federation and B2C up via OIDC. Note that B2C uses an OAuth extension for the policies so you need some custom code in Identity Server to support this.

You can also use ACS and federate this with ADFS. (Although ACS will be deprecated "soon").

Refer: [Azure B2C : Integration with IdentityServer](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2016/06/azure-b2c-integration-with.html)

Or use a third party tool e.g. Auth0 as above.

Auth0 has tons of social providers!

Comment: It appears ADFS and Azure AD B2C are now able to talk to each other using Custom Policies and the Identity Experience Framework, although it's only in preview. I already have B2C and AAD integrated (which was very fiddly), and am now adding ADFS support, referring to this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2017/06/23/using-adfs-as-an-identity-provider-for-azure-ad-b2c/

Comment: Yes - you can now do this with custom policies. But not trivial to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This use case is *trivial* if you use Auth0.

```
Your app --> Auth0 -+-> Social logins (FB, Google, etc)
                    |
                    +-> ADFS Customer 1    
                    |
                    +-> ADFS Customer 2
```

DISCLAIMER: I work there.

Comment: Can you point any good example that shows how Auth0 works with ADFS?

Comment: Dashboard > Connections > Enterprise > ADFS (https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/adfs)